# How can Ok() be both Task<IActionResult> and IActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In a `Controller` in .NET Core you can return `Ok()` as an `IActionResult`. But I do not understand how it can also return a `Task<IActionResult>`.

Example:

```
    public class FooController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OkResultAsync()
        {
            // This is ok. But I don't get why since OkResult != Task<IActionResult>
            OkResult result = Ok();
            return result;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult OkResult()
        {
            // This is ok, and it seems logical since OkResult implements IActionResult.
            OkResult result = Ok();
            return result;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public FooResult Bar()
        {
            // This is ok.
            return new FooResult();
        }

        [HttpGet] 
        public async Task<FooResult> BarAsync()
        {
            // This is not ok since FooResult != Task<FooResult>
            return new FooResult();
        }
    }
```

`Ok()` returns a [`OkResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/OkResult.cs), which in turn implements `IActionResult`. How does .NET know how to handle it (without awaiting) if the method signature is returning a `Task<IActionResult>`?

Comment: `async-await` is compiler feature, it generate code for asynchronous execution. So if you mark method as `async` compiler will wrap returned value to `Task<SomeType>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `async` keyword causes the compiler to take care of this automatically. Async methods implicitly "wrap" the return value in a Task.

```
async Task<int> GetNumber()
{
    return 42;
}
```

vs

```
Task<int> GetNumber()
{
    return Task.FromResult(42);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But why doesn't `BarAsync` in the example work?

Answer (score 1):

The async keyword is a shorthand that wraps the contents of the method in a Task. When you return inside an async method the compiler wraps it up into a Task for you. For example these two methods are essentially the same:

```
private static Task<string> Hello()
{
    return new Task<string>(() => "hello");
} 

private static async Task<string> AsyncHello()
{
    return "hello";
}
```